# Initialise variable in various switch cases

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to code the following (in C++11):

```
X x;
if( cond ) {
    x = X(foo);
}
else {
    x = X(foo, bar);
}
// ... continue using x
```

The problem is that 'X x' is going to call the default constructor and create an unwanted object of type X.

How can I solve this?  I suspect there may be some solution involving the new && operator but I can't quite see it...

Comment: A new && operator? Do tell...

Comment: `X x = cond ? X(foo) : X(foo, bar)`?

Comment: @Casey: There's potentially a move (or copy)...

Comment: I think @Casey 's solution is fine because it did not invoke the default ctor.

Comment: Wait up, that code is only to illustrate the task. The actual code is much uglier.  Ternary operator is not going to hack it.

Answer (score 5):

Use this to avoid any temporaries:

```
auto&& x = cond ? X(foo) : X(foo, bar);
```

If the initialization is more complex, employ a lambda:

```
auto&& x = [&]()->X{
    if(cond1)
        return {};
    if(cond2)
        return {foo};
    return {foo, bar};
}();
```

Used universal-references, and the lambda takes by reference, to avoid useless copies.

Also used list-initialization without unnamed temporary so no copy may take place for the lambda's return.

Be aware that list-initialization-syntax favors a ctor expecting an initializer-list.
You have to rely on RVO in that case instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use the conditional operator if the amount of cases is considerably small:

```
auto&& x = cond? X(foo) : X(foo, bar);
```

Or a lambda:

```
auto&& x = [=] // choose default-capture appropriately.
{
    if (cond) {
        return X(foo);
    }
    else {
        return X(foo, bar);
    }
}();
```

In both cases copy elision will help to eliminate any potential moves or copies, so a reference as the type for `x` isn't really necessary.

You can also use list initialization in the `return` statements to avoid any moves or copies at all (although this wouldn't produce equivalent behavior for some classes, try it out):

```
auto&& x = [=]() -> X // Note the trailing return type.
{
    if (cond) {
        return {foo};
    }
    else {
        return {foo, bar};
    }
}();
```

Comment: I think you meant aggregate initialisation, not list initialisation.

Comment: @Walter No, I meant list initialization. *copy-list-initialization* to be precise. aggregate-initialization applies to aggregates only, whilst `X` may be none.

Comment: BTW: The argument-list is not optional when you use trailing-return-type.

Comment: Beware using that. If `X` has two constructors, one taking, say, two `int` and another taking a `std::initialiser_list<int>`, which do you think are you calling???

Comment: @Walter That's why I said it won't produce equivalent behavior for some classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the easiest would be to use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) for that:

```
#include "boost/optional.hpp"

boost::optional<X> x;

if (cond) {
  x = X(foo);
} else {
  x = X(foo, bar);
}
// ... continue using *x where you would have used x
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to/can't use Boost, and you know that each of the branches will perform the initialisation, you could use `std::aligned_storage` and placement new:

```
std::aligned_storage<X> xStorage;
X *x;

if (cond) {
  x = new (&xStorage) X(foo);
} else {
  x = new (&xStorage) X(foo, bar);
}
// ... continue using *x where you would have used x
```

Note that the latter requires you to manually call the destructor eventually.

Comment: easier than `std::aligned_storage`: Use an anonymous union just wrapping one `X`. Still, union or not, the second way has unfavorable implications for exception-safety (unless X has a trivial dtor), and the first potentially uses more space&time.